# Angular ng2 google chart not updating with new data

Tags: angular, charts, datatable, dataset

I'm working on a covid-19 tracking app using angular. My problem right now is making google chart update the moment new data is been selected. when whenever I initially select data from a specific country, the graph updates then after that there no update even though I can see in console that data is changing.

```
    pieChart: GoogleChartInterface = {
  chartType: 'PieChart',
}



 pcharttwo(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    let data =[];
    data.push(['Task','Hours']);
    // data.push(['todo',parseInt(this.globalData.active)])
    data.push(['cases',parseInt(this.globalData.cases)])
    this.pieChart = {
    chartType: 'PieChart',
    dataTable:data,
    //firstRowIsData: true,
    options: {'title': 'Tasks',
              'width': 700,
              'height': 600},
  };

  this.isavailable=true
  }, 2000);
}
```

//html

```
<google-chart [data]="pieChart"  *ngIf="isavailable==true"></google-chart>
```

Comment: The draw method on the chart must be called when the data or options change, in order to update...

Comment: I looked in the documentation, there is nor a draw method.

Comment: it's on the [ChartWrapper Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods_2), which is what this angular package uses...

Answer (score 1):

The draw method is located on the component.
You need to get the component and then call the draw method.

```
redrawChart() {
  let ccComponent = this.pieChart.component;
  //force a redraw
  ccComponent.draw();
}
```